# Changing .x property does nothing, but .body.property works

Tags: javascript, socket.io, phaser-framework

I have a multiplayer game where multiple clients are pulling on a central object. I want to synchronise the position of that object between clients, for example if one of them switches tabs for a while.

This is in my update function :

```
    // update velocities of main object to those received from the server
    ball.body.velocity.y = game.y;
    ball.body.velocity.x = game.x;

    // does nothing
    ball.x = 600;

    // works as expected, pinning ball to x 600
    ball.body.x = 600;
```

Why does this happen ? I know .x and .body.x should be the same with physics enabled on a sprite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, .body.x and .x are different. According to phaser.io,

> All physics operations should be performed against the body rather than the Sprite itself.

So, if sprite has body, then use .body. When those two properties are used in wrong situation, it simply does not work probably due to physics engine applied to the object. Here is my guideline for using which for what:

Use .body.x on any object(s) that has physics enabled, such as sprites, groups, platforms, etc.

Use .x on any object(s) that does not have physics engine enabled, such as tile sprites, particles(most of times), other decorative sprites that has no interaction with other objects.